# How can I schedule a cron job but not execute it?

Tags: cron

I wanted to create a crontab file with schedule but do not want it to run. 
How can I achieve this?

I created a crontab file using `crontab -e`, added the job. This has started running. I do not want this to run as the job should be scheduled ad hoc.

I wanted to prepare and keep and use the schedule on ad hoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can comment your schedule line out with a leading `#`, and remove the comment marker again when you want it to run.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html

Answer (score 1):

You could test for a file to be present and if it does it'll execute your task:

```
5 * * * * user test -f /var/lock/subsys/myfile && /home/user/backup.sh
```

Thus when you are ready. You just

```
touch /var/lock/subsys/myfile
```

and the script starts within the next five minutes.

But you have to make sure to remove the lock file afterwards.